# JVM + Linux + Intel's Hyperthreading = 

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jvm, hyperthreading

I noticed that JVM threads run as processes under Linux for some reasons (correct me if I'm wrong). Furthermore, it is a fact that Intel's Hyperthreading provides additional parallelization only for two threads belonging to same process.

Does that mean that a single multitheraded JVM program would **not** profit from Hyperthreading under Linux, because its threads are no threads from the CPUs "point of view"?

Comment: To the best of my understanding, JVM threads on linux are just native threads, not processes.  I don't think the JVM-threads-as-processes thing has been true for a while.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Processes and threads are not treated differently by the scheduler in Linux. There are a range of resources that can be shared by processes, as defined by the [`clone`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) system call. Threads and processes as they're typically used are just names for commonly used recipes.

If you're observing threads as processes in the JVM, this is just a mixing of nomenclature. By the usual definition if processes are sharing a virtual address space, then they are "threads" within a process.

All hardware scheduling will benefit from hyper-threading, regardless of the terminology used. Also to be completely fair, hyper threading does not allow you to run more threads in parallel: it makes context switches faster, giving processes more run time.

Answer (score 1):

"JVM threads run as processes under Linux "-- No they run as LWP(Light Weight Process).

Java threads are internally implemented as native threads i.e. LWP (in linux) and you can see them using `ps -eLf`. Though mapping between a native thread and a java thread is difficult. The only thread that can be mapped easily is the main-thread as it will have the id same as the process id.

JVM will definitely profit from HT. 
From an article on [HT in java](http://java.sys-con.com/node/37663):

> SMT holds the promise of significantly increasing Java's server-side
>   performance by more completely utilizing existing processor cycles in
>   multithreaded applications.